KOMA-Script issue with DIV=calc
The following code:
\documentclass[DIV=calc, headsepline, twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\KOMAoption{DIV}{last}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}

generates an warning from typearea:
Package typearea Warning: page content and margins higher than paper. This may result in page footer out of paper. You should decrease DIV, decrease foot height, or include footer into type area.
The effect on the pdf is that the footer being eatten. The sufficient condition for generating such issue is:
DIV=calc and headsepline, and twocolumn

Disabling any of the option, the issue will vanish. With the options discribed above, the calculated DIV is 42, which is way too large. Changing it to 28 would render the document correctly without significantly changing characters per line. I am new to KOMA-Script, so  not sure if specifying DIV with factor is expected here.
Any help would be much appreciated!

With option twocolumn, option DIV=calc tries to make each column about 66 characters wide. This does not work with A4. So removing DIV=calc or using DIV=classic or doing your own decision like DIV=12 would be better. For more information about DIV=calc see the KOMA-Script manual. BTW: For moving the footer upwards also option footinclude=true can be useful. And if the header should not be part of the typing area despite using headsepline see option headinclude in the KOMA-Script manual.

BTW: If you neither change the baseline skip or stretch nor the font in the document preamble your \KOMAoption{DIV}{last} makes not sense.

With option twocolumn, option DIV=calc tries to make each column about 66 characters wide. This does not really work with A4. So removing DIV=calc to use the predefined value:
\documentclass[headsepline, twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{headings}% otherwise option headsepline does not really make sense
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}


or using DIV=classic:
\documentclass[DIV=classic,headsepline, twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{headings}% otherwise option headsepline does not really make sense
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}


is a better choice. You can also select your own value. For this, DIV=calc can indeed be a good starting point. With DIV=calc package typearea write following information to the log file:
DIV calculation for typearea with good linewidth.
Package typearea Info: Maybe no optimal type area settings!
(typearea)             The detected line width is about 22%
(typearea)             smaller than the heuristically estimated maximum
(typearea)             limit of typographical good line width.
(typearea)             You could e.g. increase DIV, decrease fontsize
(typearea)             or change the papersize.
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 42
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 554.8288pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = 22%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = -50.93042pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = -50.93042pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 759.00034pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -52.14983pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1799.

Now, you know, that DIV=42 would be the same. With DIV=classic on the other hand, it shows:
DIV calculation for classic typearea.
Package typearea Info: Maybe no optimal type area settings!
(typearea)             The detected line width is about 40%
(typearea)             smaller than the heuristically estimated maximum
(typearea)             limit of typographical good line width.
(typearea)             You could e.g. increase DIV, decrease fontsize
(typearea)             or change the papersize.
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = 40%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 17.3562pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 17.3562pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 555.00024pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = 12.2347pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1799.

So you know, that a value between these would be a good idea and can, e.g., try DIV=15:

BTW: You can test the result of not using a DIV, using DIV=calc, and using DIV=classic in a single LaTeX run. Just do:
\documentclass[headsepline, twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\KOMAoption{DIV}{calc}
\KOMAoption{DIV}{classic}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{headings}% otherwise option headsepline does not really make sense
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}

to have three information output like shown above in the log file.
Please see the KOMA-Script manuals (mainly chapter 2) for more information about the DIV defaults, DIV=calc, and DIV=classic.
BTW: For moving the footer upwards also option footinclude=true can be useful:
\documentclass[DIV=calc,footinclude,headsepline, twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{headings}% otherwise option headsepline does not really make sense
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}


But IMHO the margins here are still too small.
For information about how option headsepline influences the setting of option headinclude and how you can revert, also see the KOMA-Script manual.
Notes:

I've removed your \KOMAoption{DIV}{last}, because this does not change anything in the example. Without changing the paper size, the font size, the font, or the baseline skip or stretch the recalculation would have the same result as before.
I've also remove \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}, because it is also irrelevant for the result.
I've added \pagestyle{headings}, because without a running head (either with automatic content or manual added content) option headsepline would not really make sense IMHO. So, when using scrlayer-scrpage it would make sense, to load the package either with option automark or use command \automark[…]{…} or add some content to the header using, e.g., \chead{…}.

BTW: You can read the first note also as: If you use another font size, e.g., option fontsize=10pt, or another font the resulting DIV value of DIV=calc can be different.
